# Integrating database with google static map markers (overlays)

Tags: asp.net, database, google-maps

I cant find the way to create overlays on the static google map through database. I can acheive the a single marker(location) easily. below is the code:

int mapID = Convert.ToInt16(hdnMapID.Value);
        SqlDataReader dr =  Maps.GetMapPointsByMapIDUserID(mapID, userID);

```
   string latitude = "53.615143";
   string longitude = "-1.711380";
    string center = "" + latitude + "," + longitude + "";
    string zoom = "20";
    string size = "512x512";
    string maptype = "roadmap";

    while (dr.Read())
    {


            map2.ImageUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + center + "&zoom=" + zoom + " &size=" + size + "&maptype=" + maptype + "&markers=color:blue|label:S|" + dr["lat"] + ", " + dr["lng"] + "&sensor=true";
        }



        cnt++;
    }
    dr.Dispose();
```

In the above url, its easy to pass marker value (color:blue|label:S|"+ dr["lat"] + "," + dr["lng"] +) for a single location, but in my project I have got multiple locations and I cant find a way to create different urls for multiple locations for instance if there are two locations there will be 2 markers in the above url, how can I create programatically google static url depending on the numbers of markers(overlays) present in the map.

Any tutorial or help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edition of the post #1 by M'vy*

Ok. I think I got the point. So I edit the answer to use the code snippet.
The following code has to be used for **ONE** `mapId`

```
int mapID = Convert.ToInt16(hdnMapID.Value); 
/* I suppose this executes the following SQL query : 
 * SELECT lat, lng FROM Table WHERE mapID = :mapID;
 */
SqlDataReader dr = Maps.GetMapPointsByMapIDUserID(mapID, userID);

string latitude = "53.615143";
string longitude = "-1.711380";
string center = "" + latitude + "," + longitude + "";
string zoom = "20";
string size = "512x512";
string maptype = "roadmap";

/* This is the basic link, with no markers */
string URLStart = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
center + "&zoom=" + zoom + " &size=" + size + "&maptype=" + maptype + "&sensor=true";

string markersStr = "";

/* Each record we will read correspond to one point on the map: 
 * NB you don't need the markerID 
 * We add each point long and lat to the string */
while (dr.Read()) {
    markersStr += "&markers=color:blue|label:S|" + dr["lat"] + ", " + dr["lng"] + ;
}

map2.ImageUrl = URLStart + markersStr;
dr.Dispose();

//Then display the map with the URL that has all the point for mapId
```

The `markerId` is of no use. You can easily compute the value by using
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE mapID = 581;

---

*First Post*

Hello Muhammad,

You can find your answer in the Google Map Static API [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

For multiple markers, you just have to repeat the markers parameter in the URL.
You can choose a different color, name etc. Just append a new `&markers=<blah blah>`

M'vy

Comment: hi , I know how to do that, repeating marker is an issue , coz my client have different locations everytime he set up a customer, therefore my url wont be constant it has to change depending on the locations selected.

Comment: I don't really get the problem in that case. Can't you just refresh the map, by reading the database one more time?

Comment: each customer saved map is defined by mapID which can have a single or multiple locations, I have got a section in which customer can look different maps saved by him. the problem is I cant find the way I can draw map with multiple location, for a single location it can be acheived by passinng its long and latitude parameters to the url but for multiple location which can 2,3,4 or etc how can the system setup the url for multiple locations.

Comment: at present the markers passing previously are sitting on top of each other - thus overwriting the previous one

Comment: I bet the idea is then to read the database records before generating the URL. I guess you can know how much locations you have to display? Then you read the records from the DB, append &markers=color:blue|label:S|" + dr["lat"] + ", " + dr["lng"] to a string, and finally generate the full URL with a concatenation. Would it be ok that way?

Comment: I have got a field names markerID, which determines how much location each map have , so I can have a if then else statement like:

Comment: string check = dr["lat"];
            if (Convert.ToInt16(dr["markerID"]) > 0)
            {

                map2.ImageUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + dr["lat"] + "," + dr["lng"] + "&zoom=" + zoom + " &size=" + size + "&maptype=" + maptype + "&markers=color:blue|label:S|" + dr["lat"] + ", " + dr["lng"] + "&sensor=true";
            }

Comment: do u know ny logic of creating url automatically ,

Comment: the problem is , dere is no limit of locations , it can be 12 , can be 15 , therefore I cant create too many urls and then apply loop statement like if else.

Comment: May you clarify a thing? A map has one mapID and all maps are stored in let's say the Maps table. Then you have a second table for markers, let's call it Markers with associates two coords to one mapId and each marker has a markerID. Am I right?

Comment: for instance there is map named "Home" which has three locations means three latitude and longitude parameters. Its mapID will be unique and markerID will be 3 becuase it has three locations. Thats how I can determine how many locations a map have. Hopee you get it ..

Comment: Can you paste an example of the DB structure and data? I can't picture how you store the different long and lat within one record? Is a single field with comma separated values? Example if I want to store a map with 3 locations, how do I do that?

Comment: mapPointID mapID markerID name lat lng
752 581 0 Home 53.514576 -2.232892
753 581 1 test99 53.514061 -2.234652
754 582 0 Home 53.514576 -2.232892
755 582 1 l1 53.514431 -2.234566
756 582 2 l2 53.513882 -2.234523

Comment: I cant attach the visuals of data design .

Comment: I will use the above code tomorrow nd let u know , not in the office yet.. by the thnx a lot for your help. really appreciate ur assistance. This is the first time i m working on google map api, nd infact just made an account on stackoverflow for this query.

Comment: Ok no problem, my pleasure. Don't forget to mark a resolve if it is. Or feel free to ask more if not.

Comment: Dat works fine bro, thnx a lot, Also If I want to change the color of label , let suppose different color for each label, do I have run the loop within a loop to acheive that

Comment: I would use a FIFO list (init). Read the head and delete (in the loop).

Comment: neva used FIFO before ,can you provide a simple example of it.

Comment: Try : `List<String> colors; colors.Add("green"); colors.Add("red");` then in the loop you get the `colors[0]` then do a `colors.Remove()`. You can also just parse the list using a counter and `colors[i]`. You can find the documentation at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: List<string> colors = new List<string>();
        colors.Add("green");
      
        colors.Add("red");
        int i = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            markersStr += "&markers=color:" + colors[i] + "|" + dr["lat"] + ", " + dr["lng"] +"" ;
            colors.Remove("green");
           
        } map2.ImageUrl = URLStart + markersStr;
        dr.Dispose();

Comment: I tried the above code that works fine for as I want the first location labelled in green colour while others labelled as red. Thnx ... How can select ur above comment as an answer

Comment: Hum, I think you can mark it a `great comment`with the up arrow that appears when you move the cursor next to the comment? Happy to know it's working. Good luck!

Comment: No problem. Can't do it myself but it's just an answer to a sub-question. Thanks anyway.